# Gulp - Accessing gulpfile variable from AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, node.js, web-services, gulp

I have a service where I manage my requests to a webservice and actually I have defined the webservice url on this service:

```
(function ()
{
    angular.module("MyProject")

    .factory("Webservice", ["$http", function ($http)
    {
        var URLbase = function ()
        {
            //return "http://myproject.link.pt/Service/Service.svc/";
            return "http://localhost/MyProject/Service.svc/";
        }

        var login = function (param) {
            var serviceURL = URLbase() + "ValidateLogin";
            return $http.post(serviceURL, JSON.stringify({ username: param.Username, password: param.Password }));
          }
        var loginResult = function (response) {
            return exists(response) && exists(response.data) && exists(response.data.ValidateLoginResult)
                ? response.data.ValidateLoginResult
                : null;
        }

        return {
            Login: login,
            LoginResult: loginResult
        }
    }])
})();
```

But when I need to publish my project I frequently forget to comment and uncomment the paths on the `URLbase()`.

There is any way to do this on the `gulpfile.js`?

On my `gulpfile.js` I have two different tasks to build for development or for production and I thought that was nice if I could done that management there:

```
gulp.task('build-development', function (done)
{
    config.minify = false;

    var tasks = ['html', 'resources', 'assets', 'sass', 'js', 'vendors'];
    seq('clean', tasks, done);
});

gulp.task('build-production', function (done)
{
    config.minify = true;

    var tasks = ['html', 'resources', 'assets', 'sass', 'js', 'vendors'];
    seq('clean', tasks, function() {
        notifier.notify({ title: 'Project publishment', message: 'Done' });
    });
});
```

I already tried to create a variable on my `gulpfile.js` an access it on a AngularJS file but I got an error saying that variable isn't defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a placeholder in your webservice:

```
var URLbase = function ()
{
    return "URL_BASE_FOR_WEBSERVICE";
}
```

Add both URLs to your `config` object:

```
gulp.task('build-development', function (done)
{
    config.minify = false;
    config.urlBaseForWebService = "http://localhost/MyProject/Service.svc/";

    var tasks = ['html', 'resources', 'assets', 'sass', 'js', 'vendors'];
    seq('clean', tasks, done);
});

gulp.task('build-production', function (done)
{
    config.minify = true;
    config.urlBaseForWebService = "http://myproject.link.pt/Service/Service.svc/";

    var tasks = ['html', 'resources', 'assets', 'sass', 'js', 'vendors'];
    seq('clean', tasks, function() {
        notifier.notify({ title: 'Project publishment', message: 'Done' });
    });
});
```

Finally in your `js` task use [`gulp-replace`](https://npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to replace the `URL_BASE_FOR_WEBSERVICE` placeholder with the value of `config.urlBaseForWebService`:

```
 var replace = require('gulp-replace');

 gulp.task('js', function() {
   return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
     .pipe(replace(/URL_BASE_FOR_WEBSERVICE/, config.urlBaseForWebService))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
 });
```

Comment: Really nice solution. Works perfectly! Thanks a lot